# Since we have that $\tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{1}{s} \right) + \tan^{-1}(s) = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, does this not imply that $s > 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

I'm currently studying the textbook *An Introduction to Laplace Transforms and Fourier Series*, second edition, by Phil Dyke. Chapter **2.2 Derivative Property of the Laplace Transform** says the following:

> The function
> $$Si(t) = \int_0^t \dfrac{\sin(u)}{u} \ du$$
> defines the Sine Integral function which occurs in the study of optics. The formula for its Laplace Transform can now be easily derived as follows.
> Let $F(t) = \sin(t)$ in the result
> $$\mathcal{L} \left( \dfrac{F(t)}{t} \right) = \int_s^\infty f(u) \ du$$
> to give
> $$\begin{align*} \mathcal{L} \left( \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t} \right) &= \int_s^\infty \dfrac{du}{1 + u^2} \\ &= \left[ \tan^{-1}(u) \right]_s^\infty \\ &= \dfrac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1}(s) \\ &= \tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{1}{s} \right). \end{align*}$$

So, in the last part, we have that $\dfrac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1}(s) = \tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{1}{s} \right) \Rightarrow \tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{1}{s} \right) + \tan^{-1}(s) = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Researching this identity, I found it said that

$$\tan^{-1}(x) + \tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{1}{x} \right) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\pi}{2}, & x > 0 \\ -\dfrac{\pi}{2}, & x < 0 \end{cases}$$

And we know that, in this context of the Laplace transform, $s$ is a complex number. But I don't think the general Laplace transform requires that $s > 0$, right? But, in the above case, since we have that $\tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{1}{s} \right) + \tan^{-1}(s) = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, does this not imply that $s > 0$?

Comment: $\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - st} Si(t)dt} $ will not converge if $\Re s \leq 0$ (since $
Si(t) \sim \frac{\pi }{2}$ for large $t$). So when computing this Laplace transform, you have to assume $s>0$. Then of course you can use analytic continuation to extend it to $\Re s>0$.

Comment: @Gary Is it that the Laplace transform will *generally* not converge if $\Re\{s\} \le 0$, or is it just $\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - st} Si(t)dt}$?

Comment: It can converge for $\Re s \leq 0$ in some cases. For example if you take the transform of $e^{-ct}$ ($c>0$), the integral converges for $\Re s >-c$. It has to be investigated in each specific case.

Comment: @Gary But why does $Si(t) \sim \frac{\pi }{2}$ for large $t$ mean that $\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - st} Si(t)dt}$ will not converge if $\Re s \leq 0$?

Comment: Take for example $s=-1$, do you think $\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^t Si(t)dt}  \approx \frac{\pi }{2}\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^t dt} $ converges?

Comment: @Gary Ahh, no, it doesn't. Ok, I see what you mean. Thanks for the clarification.